# mat-expansion-panel, content doesnt recover his original height after closing a panel

Tags: angular, angular-material

Edit: I solve this issue because i was missing `div class="row"` and it make sense, without a row, when the panel have been closed, the `div class="col"` was floating there because it wasnt inside anything. Inside a row works perfect :)

Within an Angular App, I have a list of events, every one is a mat-expansion-panel from Angular Material.

After the list of events there is some HTML content, issue comes when after opening a panel and closing it, the original height of the document (with the panel closed) doesnt recover its original height.

Same happens when there's more than one event, the height of each event stacks if you opened all of them then closing them, making the document extra large.

Single Event Mat-panel

```
<div class="col s12 m12 l6 events-list animated fadeIn">
<mat-accordion class="event">
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title [ngClass]="{'title': panelOpenState == true}">
                {{event.eventName}}
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
                {{event.eventTime}}
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        {{event.eventDescription}}
        <br>
        <br>
        <button class="btn orange" (click)="createPoll(event.entityID)">Crear Tema</button>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
 </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

Events Page

```
<div class="row">
 <app-event *ngFor="let event of eventList" [event]="event"></app-event>
</div>
```

Is there any way this fix this issue? glad to see some replies :)

Example:

Page with panel closed

[image: Page with panel closed]

Page with panel opened

[image: Page with panel opened]

Page when panel have been closed (Issue here, RED SQUARE)

[image: Page when panel have been closed]

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: added and solved, anyway, check it to know if it the right solution